# annot unpack non-iterable nonetype object

Tags: pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time
for i in range(20):
    x, y= pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("threeDots.png", confidence = 1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration= 0.5 )
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    time.sleep(0.5)
   
    
    x, y= pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("Unfriend.png", confidence = 1)
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration= 0.5 )
    pyautogui.leftClick()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

line 4, in 
x, y= pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen("threeDots.png", confidence = 1)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Comment: It hasn't found the image

Answer (score -1):

imma suggest some random stuff maybe one of them work for ya:

1-check the path of the image if it is in same folder with the script file

2-check the name cuz sometimes its the letters that makes this error \ "sad,png" was my mistake i used comma instead of dot

3- try to edit the picture and save a new version from it from the "save as" option and trying the command on the new copy if works then it has something to do with the image u originally had